# Eclipse SWTBot randomly throws Widget Not Found Exception

Tags: eclipse, swtbot

I have a Simple test case to create a project, this test case works fine , **but all of a sudden, at some try the WidgetNotFound exception is thrown!! Restart the test, the exception is not thrown !!**


Again after some try WidgetNotFound  exception is thrown! Is there any particular reason for this??

This un-expected behaviour happens more often when running test through crontab! Any suggestions on how to avoid it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to get rid of these random failures was to increase the
SWTBot timing parameters to:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swtbot.playback.poll.delay=500
-Dorg.eclipse.swtbot.playback.delay=400
```

UPDATED link: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/FAQ